# upload a screenshot without save it in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, optimization, file-upload, live-streaming

I would like to take a screenshot without saving it to the disk.
All this in vb.net
Since I would like to stream the screen I run a screenshot and load it every 0.5 seconds, so it does not have to be that heavy.
Below is the code I currently use:

```
Dim timestamp As String = CLng(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(New DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds)
    Dim bounds As Rectangle
    Dim screenshot As System.Drawing.Bitmap
    Dim graph As Graphics
    bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds
    screenshot = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb)
    graph = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot)
    graph.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy)
    screenshot.Save(Path.GetTempPath & "\stream_video\screenshot.jpg", Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
 My.Computer.Network.UploadFile(Path.GetTempPath & "\stream_video\screenshot.jpg", server_total & "upload.php")
IO.File.Delete(Path.GetTempPath & "\stream_video\screenshot.jpg")
GC.Collect() 'Garbage Collection
```

how could I make it as fluid and optimized as possible?

[Sorry for my bad english].

Comment: Did you have a question?  Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  PS your code is leaking and will crash after a few minutes

Comment: Ok, corrected, thanks.

Comment: SO is not the place for questions about code that already works. Try [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: One of the overloads to `Save()` on  `Bitmap` is to a `Stream` so just use that instead of to a file.